# Should I accelerate when start the deisel engine

Tags: engine, diesel

When starting a deisel engine vehicle in the morning that was manufactured in 90's should I give accelerate.

Some are telling do not accelerate when starting the vehicle start of the day.

Give some time around 3 to 5 minutes. Then only accelerate the engine..

Some time if the battery is weak have to accelerate otherwise engine not in start.

Should I accelerate the engine in the morning when starting the van.

Comment: What do you mean by "accelerate the engine"? Does that mean you rev the engine while stationary, to make it warm up more quickly? What do you mean by "engine not in start"? How can you accelerate when the engine has not started, and why should a weak battery matter once the engine has been started? The best way to warm up a normal engine is to drive it gently, although some high-performance engines need to be warmed up first (but not by revving).

Comment: I mean once start the engine in the morning immediately should I press the accelerate or not..  one of my friend told me that when starting the engine in the morning give some time and then start your journey , don't go immediately... should I consider this?

Comment: **why should a weak battery matter once the engine has been started** this is my misconception.. let assume if I not started the vehicle for last one week and now I starting the vehicle engine get started and not continue to be in the start.. but by revving the accelerater it is be in the start mood.. sorry for the poor English..

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Start the engine when you are ready to leave, and drive off. If the engine is old and in poor condition, so it won't run properly, wait for it to warm up, with *just enough* revs to keep it running.

Comment: No need to it warm up, you should usually start driving with moderate load right away.

"Diesel engine from the 90s" is about as broad as it gets though, from NA indirection injection up to turbocharged common rail diesels, everything was at the market then.

Comment: Why would you do that?  Is the engine quitting if you don't? Start it, finish your departure preparation, then drive gently until the engine warms up.  **The best way to warm up an engine is simply drive it on the gentle side of normal**.

Comment: The only time I keep an engine revved is when *I'm* cold. Surely the engine would rather I not. [Should I avoid full throttle when driving with a cold engine?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/22440/should-i-avoid-full-throttle-when-driving-with-a-cold-engine)